# How to make Two side round corner UITextField in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I want to create uitextfield with the top left and right corner as rounded and bottom left and right corner as normal rectangle. Is there any way to create this kind of UITextField. I tried set the contentRadius property to 10.0f it gives me fully rounded rectangle textfield. Please help me to create a two side rounded corner textField.

Answer (score 0):

```
textField.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
```

Add this

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Setting up above property will give us full rounded rectangle uitextfield but I am expecting uitextfield which has upper left and right corner should be rounded lower corner should be normal.

Comment: You can try using a background image.

Comment: @kumar I think you have to use image. I dont know any other way. If you find solution please inform me.